# After Primefaces CommandButton clicked, it does not get triggered anymore

Tags: jquery, jsf, primefaces, commandbutton

Hello i have a **Primefaces commandbutton** to refresh my page. On click it calls a jQuery function which blocks the UI and then fires an actionListener method. 
The first click works fine. The page reloads and executes the refresh method. 
But when the button is clicked a second time, the jquery blocks the UI, but the actionListener method is not being executed anymore. So the screen is stuck on a blocked UI.
Why does the Button only work once? 
here is the code for the button:

```
    <p:commandButton title="Refresh" icon="ui-icon-refresh"
                     id="pageRefresh"
                     widgetVar="refreshButtonWidgetVar"
                     actionListener="#{pageBean.refreshFromButton}"
                     onclick="hideDialogs();destroyCharts();blockUI();"
                     oncomplete="unblockUI(), $(window).resize()"
                     styleClass="pageRefresh"
                     value="#{msg['label.page.refresh']}"
                     update=":pageContent"
                     process="@this"
                                        />
```

Using a breakpoint, the debugger does not go into the actionListener method code the second time the button is clicked. And on JS side i do not see any error. So i do not really know how to handle this error or where exactly the error happens. Thanks for any help

Comment: Try with a ";" instead of "," in oncomplete. Or remove the last part for testing

Comment: so when i remove the onclick and oncomplete part completely it seems to call the actionlistener method again, but that is no solution for me

Comment: seems like any js function i call, afterwards certain primefaces buttons do not work anymore